# Remove port number from Node HTTP request to external API

Tags: node.js, http, express, reactjs, webpack

I am writing a React app using Node, Express, and Webpack. My problem is that my API calls' URLs always have a port number between the host and the path. It seems like most of the questions on this topic have more to do with routing than with external API calls.

I am much more comfortable with Request, but I got very frustrated trying to get it to play nicely with Webpack, so I turned to Node's http which I know less about.

Here is the method responsible for the API call:

```
getData() {
    const self = this;

    const url = "api.civicapps.org";

    const options = {
        "method": "GET",
        "mode": "no-cors",
        "host": url,
        "path": "/restaurant-inspections/?restaurant_name=" + this.state.nameQuery,
        "port": 8080,
        "headers": {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://localhost:3000"
        }
    }

    const p1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        resolve(
            http.request(options, function(res) {
                res.setEncoding('utf8');
                const body = {};

                //This is clearly not ideal, but all I need right now is to get a response from the API

                res.on('data', function(chunk) {
                    body.push(chunk);
                });
                return body;
            }).end()
        )   
    });

    p1.then(function(data) {
            console.log(data);

        self.setState({
            name: data.body
        });
    });

    p1.catch(function(err) {

        ...
    });
}
```

All I want to do is a simple test GET request to this API. Once that's working, I will be fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What port are you referring to? You're including a port (`8080`) in the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out setting the port to 80 and running with sudo solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know this topic is old, but I think it's good to share my experience with a similar issue in a **Docker environment**.

Since I was calling a service as hostname in my Node container, I didn't want the port to be set after the service name (e.g.: `http://my-api-service/v1/users` was called as `http://my-api-service/v1/users:80`).

I didn't reach to figure it out so I used [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios). It has its own definition types and can be used like that:

```
import Axios, { AxiosRequestConfig } from 'axios';
...

const options: AxiosRequestConfig = {
  headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token, 'Accept': 'application/ld+json' }
};

Axios.get('http://my-api-service/v1/users', options)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error: " + error.message);
  })
  .then(() => {
    // always executed
    // ...
  });
```

This is the only way I found to solve that kind of errors with a Dockerized environment.